# Apache CXF Client for WCF Soap WS

Tags: wcf, web-services, cxf, webservice-client

I'm creating a java client with CXF 2.7.0 to an WCF web service that uses SOAP.
I've used the wsdl2java tool to generate the classes needed to communicate with web service.

My problem is that in the web service on the endpoint binding the reliableSession is enabled and because of this when i try to send a message to the web service with cxf I get

```
Oct 19, 2012 1:11:59 AM org.apache.cxf.ws.rm.Proxy invoke
INFO: Sending out-of-band RM protocol message {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/rm}CreateSequence.
Oct 19, 2012 1:11:59 AM org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain doDefaultLogging
WARNING: Interceptor for {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/rm}SequenceAbstractService#{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/rm}CreateSequence has thrown exception, unwinding now
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Could not send Message.
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:64)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:271)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:531)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:464)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:376)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.rm.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:287)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.rm.Proxy.createSequence(Proxy.java:183)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.rm.RMManager.getSequence(RMManager.java:448)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.rm.RMOutInterceptor.handle(RMOutInterceptor.java:152)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.rm.AbstractRMInterceptor.handleMessage(AbstractRMInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:271)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:531)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:464)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:367)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:320)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:89)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:134)
        at .........
```

Does anyone know how to enable the reliableSession in CXF?

Comment: if you get answer please post it because  i face same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try cxf version 2.5.4 instead of 2.7.0.

Comment: can you please explain in detail. Is it a version problems ??